# Nested if-else statement not working probably

Tags: c++, if-statement, control-flow

i need some assistance with the program. When the number of people is greater than the maximum number of people allowed in the room, the last statement does not print. I am not sure if i did something wrong, or missed an important item. I don't think i need to include a Boolean expression in the last else statement according to the text i am using, this is why i did not use any boolean expression there
Please assist. Thanks for your help

```
//Write a program that determines whether a meeting room is in violation of fire law regulations regarding the maximum room capacity. 
//The program will read in the maximum room capacity and the number of people to attend the meeting. If the number of people is less than 
//or equal to the maximum room capacity, the program announces that it is legal to hold the meeting and tells how many additional people 
//may legally attend. If the number of people exceeds the maximum room capacity, the program announces that the meeting cannot be held as 
//planned due to fire regulations and tells how many people must be excluded in order to meet the fire regulations.

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//variable declaration
int numberOfPeople, maxRoomCapacity, morePeople, lessPeople;

//program ask user of input
cout << "Enter the number of people to attend the meeting: ";
cin >> numberOfPeople;
cout << "What is the room capacity: ";
cin >> maxRoomCapacity;

//formula to calculate the number of people that meets fire regulation
morePeople = maxRoomCapacity - numberOfPeople;
lessPeople = numberOfPeople - maxRoomCapacity;

//if-else statement to determine if fire regulation is met
if (numberOfPeople < maxRoomCapacity)
{
    cout << "It is legal to hold the meeting in the room, plus " << morePeople
        << " additional people may legally attend the meeting." << endl;
}
else if (maxRoomCapacity = numberOfPeople)
{
    cout << "It is legal to hold the meeting in the room, no additional person can be allowed." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "This meeting cannot be held as planned due to fire regulations. "
        << lessPeople << " people must be excluded in order to meet the fire regulations." << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: It's best to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), instead of running to SO for help.

Comment: If your compiler isn't giving you a warning for `else if (maxRoomCapacity = numberOfPeople)` you don't have the warnings turned up high enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your else-if statement, instead of comparing the two variables, you assigned `numberOfPeople` to `maxRoomCapacity`. The assignment evaluates to true, causing  the body of that if-else to execute, causing the flow of your program to skip the `else` statement.

The problem is here:

```
else if (maxRoomCapacity = numberOfPeople)
```

change it to:

```
else if (maxRoomCapacity == numberOfPeople)
```

Notice that:

- `=` is an assignment operator
- `==` is a comparison operator

---

Compile with warnings (e.g. `-Wall` for GCC), and you should get:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:26:26: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
 else if (maxRoomCapacity = numberOfPeople)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Thank you so much @gsamaras. I forgot the difference between assignment operator and comparison operator. I am so sorry for bothering you all. I am a newbie. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know. Just accepted it. Thanks